# UICollectionView Full Screen Vertically and 2 Screens Horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that displays one cell at a time that has the size equals to the `UIViewController.view.bounds.size`. This works great for me on Vertical/Portrait screen.

I want to rotate the screen to landscape and a nice animation happens to show 2 cells side by side each having size equals to `CGSize(UIViewController.view.bounds.width / 2, UIViewController.view.bounds.height)`

Is there a library that does that or how can I achieve this approach?

You can think of it as an image gallery that displays one image at a time when rotated should show 2 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using flow layout, then all you have to do is implement `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` delegate methods, and invalidate the collectionView's layout on rotation.
Take a look at this repo: [dynamic width cells](https://github.com/almas73/demo-DynamicWidthCollectionViewCells/blob/Option_6_viewWillLayoutSubviews/DynamicWidthCollectionViewCells/OptionSixViewController.swift)

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but you can get a general idea.

Comment: You gave me a great idea. Custom layout from UICollectionViewFlowLayout does the trick.

Comment: No problem. If that helped you, then please accept the answer.